# Linux - How to copy recursive from each folder N files and keep same folder structure

Tags: linux, shell, command

I need to copy from each sub folder 10 files/images recursively.

```
/dir1 
├── subdir1 
│   ├── file1 
│   └── fileN
│
├── subdir2 
│   ├── file1 
│   └── fileN 
│
├── subdir3 
│   ├── file1 
│   └── fileN 
│
└── subdirN 
    ├── file1 
    └── fileN 
...
```

result should be:

```
/newdir1 
├── subdir1 
│   ├── file1 
│   └── file10 
│
├── subdir2 
│   ├── file1 
│   └── file10 
│
├── subdir3 
│   ├── file1 
│   └── file10 
│
└── subdirN 
    ├── file1 
    └── file10 
...
```

Directory structure should be the same but each folder should have max. 10 random files from each original folder in it.

How can I do this with a shell script?

Comment: Use `cp` command with `-r` option.

Comment: I would like to copy from each folder eg. 10 files. in each folder is a different amount of files.

Comment: first 10, last 10, or maybe random 10?

Comment: random :) but any works

Comment: OK, and where do you want to copy them, into a single directory?

Comment: no, the folder structure should remain the same :) Thank you so much!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125917/discussion-between-domi771-and-ruslan-osmanov).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you don't want to copy all files (which suggested by `cp -r` command), but only n files.

Let's say we have a directory called `foo` and need to move `n=10` files from each subdirectory to the specific location called `bar`. So, shell script loop will look like this.

```
#!/bin/bash

for subdir in $(find ~/foo -type d); do
  subdir_relative=$(echo $subdir | sed 's:.*foo/::g')
  mkdir "$subdir_relative"
  for file in $(find "$subdir" -type f | head -n 10); do
    cp "$file" "~/bar/$subdir_relative/"
  done
done
```

Comment: thank you! my description is not perfect. I would like to keep the current folder structure in place.

Comment: you will, don't worry. It's just copying files, but not moving

Comment: your code fails with directory names containing spaces, e.g. `a b c`

Comment: sure, I fixed this bug wrapping directory name into double quotes; thanks for attention

Comment: What I mean is that within the bar folder all the subfolders from the foo folder should still exist and each should have N (eg. 10) files in it. Not all files should be within the bar folder just. Hope its understandable

Comment: Got you. I changed the script, each new subdirectory should contain no more than 10 files. Try